# concurrent install of git multiple branches of an R package with `devtools::install_github()`

Tags: r, git, devtools

As the title states: is it possible to install multiple git branches of the same package side-by-side in the same R environment? I want to do some benchmarking and it would be easier to compare the two branches in the same session. I think one workaround is to change the package name in the DESCRIPTION file in the new branch, but is there a more clever way to do this with `devtools`?

Sample code:

```
devtools::install_github("mkoohafkan/RAStestR", ref = "master")
# overwrites the prior install
devtools::install_github("mkoohafkan/RAStestR", ref = "hdf5r_transition")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. At least not without an extra layer.  Read on.

While `git` (the protocol, as well as the client) support "branches" akin to a virtual filesystem allowing you to switch easily, R does not.

For every package you install, one and only one version can be installed.

But don't despair, because the *file system* can be used as a backend, and R can then *switch by adjusting the library path*.  This is all in `help(Startup)` but it may help to be explicit.

What you can do (and I mock this here)

```
mkdir master; cd master; installFromBranch.R master; cd ..
mkdir featureA; cd featureA; installFromBranch.R featureA; cd ..
mkdir featureB; cd featureA; installFromBranch.R featureB; cd ..
```

and then in R use, say,

```
.libPaths("master"); library("mypackage")
```

or if you want a feature

```
.libPaths("featureA"); library("mypackage")
```

You can also use `R_LIB_USER=featureA Rscript -e '.....someCommandHere...'`

So in short: map the *branches* to *directories* into which you install and tell R about those directories.

Comment: Interesting solution---but it looks like this will allow me to use *either* version, but not *both versions at the same time*. Is there a way to set an alias for one of the packages on load?

Comment: No. As I said right at the beginning, _R only knows one version of each package_ so you would at minimum have to compare via two _distinct_ R sessions using eg what I described. It's how R is organized.